# SimpleAudioPlayer CurrentPosition and Duration are always 0

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.uwp

I'm trying to make a playlist in Xamarin Forms using a list of audios that can be added in a `ListView` through other `ListView`s.
I'm using the [SimpleAudioPlayer plugin](https://github.com/adrianstevens/Xamarin-Plugins/tree/master/SimpleAudioPlayer) in order to reach this.
I would like to get multiple audios played consecutively.

The play function is working fine and the `Stream` doesn't throw any `Exception`.
Right now, the code plays always the same audio multiple times.
To reach the consecutive effect, I tried to make a while loop using `CurrentPosition` and `Duration` properties inside a for loop for each track in the playlist, but I didn't find any self esplicative documentation about these two properties.

```cs
using G.Models;
using Plugin.SimpleAudioPlayer;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Windows.Input;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace G.ViewModels
{
    class ABSViewModel : BaseViewModel{
        public ObservableCollection<PlayListItem> Playlist { get; set; }
        public ICommand PlayPlaylistCommand { get; set; }
        private PlayListItem playlistSelectedItem;
        public PlayListItem PlaylistSelectedItem
        { 
            get {
                return playlistSelectedItem;
            }
            set {
                playlistSelectedItem = value;
            }
        }

        public ABSViewModel()
        {
            audio = CrossSimpleAudioPlayer.CreateSimpleAudioPlayer();
            PlayButtonText = "PLAY";
            PlayButtonImage = "play_icon.png";
            PlayButtonFlag = "1";
            PlayPlaylistCommand = new Command(PlayPlaylist);
            Playlist = new ObservableCollection<PlayListItem>();
        }

        private async void PlayPlaylist()
        {
            if (PlayButtonFlag == "1")
            {
                PlayButtonText = "PAUSE";
                PlayButtonImage = "pause_icon.png";
                PlayButtonFlag = "0";
                int startPosition;

                if(PlaylistSelectedItem != null)
                {
                    startPosition = 0;
                }
                else
                {
                    startPosition = Playlist.IndexOf(playlistSelectedItem);
                }
                for(int i = 0; i < Playlist.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (audio.IsPlaying) audio.Stop();
                    PlaylistSelectedItem = Playlist[i];
                    OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Playlist));
                    audio.Load(GetStreamFromFile(Playlist[i].Name + ".wav"));
                    audio.Play();
                    while (audio.CurrentPosition != audio.Duration) {
                        Debug.WriteLine("Test");
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                PlayButtonText = "PLAY";
                PlayButtonImage = "play_icon.png";
                PlayButtonFlag = "1";
                if (audio.IsPlaying) audio.Pause();
            }
            NotifyButtonChange();
        }


        Stream GetStreamFromFile(string filename)
        {
            var assembly = typeof(App).GetTypeInfo().Assembly;
            var stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("G2019." + "RSNZBile.wav");
            return stream;
        }

        private void NotifyButtonChange()
        {
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(PlayButtonText));
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(PlayButtonImage));
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(PlayButtonFlag));
        }

    }
}
```

I omit the `Command`s to add elements to the playlist or to stop the playlist from playing because I think they are out of context.
Now, when I press the "Play" button, I see in the debugger that my `while` cycle did not start at all. So, the player plays all the elements of the playlist in few milliseconds and the only one the human can hear is the last one. That is because my `CurrentPosition` and `Duration` properties are both set to 0. Why?
Did anyone try to do something like this?

Comment: quick look says this line in the `for` loop isn't right. `if (audio.IsPlaying) audio.Stop();`  stopping the track at the beginning of the for loop doesnt seem right

Comment: @SWilko The `if (audio.IsPlaying) audio.Stop();` is there to make sure that the player doesn't yell at me during runtime because I'm trying to open two audios in the same `Stream`. It should be executed **after** the `while` in any case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone is interested, I solved the problem using `PlaybackEnded` event.
Every piece of code that was inside the `for` loop was moved inside the `PlaybackEnded` handler function with no need of a `while`. The `Duration` value set to `0` is still a mystery.

```cs
private async void PlayPlaylist(string value)
{
    if (PlayButtonMode == 1)
    {
        int startPosition;
        //Playing playlist from selected item if user selected one. (first item if he didn't)
        if (PlaylistSelectedItem == null) startPosition = 0;
        else startPosition = Playlist.IndexOf(playlistSelectedItem);
        if (audio.IsPlaying) audio.Stop();
        PlaylistSelectedItem = Playlist[startPosition];
        audio.Load(GetStreamFromFile(PlaylistSelectedItem.Name + ".wav"));
        audio.Play();
        audio.PlaybackEnded += Audio_PlaybackEnded;
    }
    else if (PlayButtonMode == 2)
        audio.Play();
    else
    {
        if (audio.IsPlaying) audio.Pause();
    }
    ChangeButtonMode(PlayButtonMode);
}

private void ChangeButtonMode(int senderMode)
{
    if (senderMode == 1 || senderMode == 2)
    {
        PlayButtonText = "PAUSE";
        PlayButtonImage = "pause_icon.png";
        PlayButtonMode = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        PlayButtonText = "PLAY";
        PlayButtonImage = "play_icon.png";
        if (senderMode == 3) PlayButtonMode = 1; 
        else PlayButtonMode = 2;
    }
    NotifyButtonChange();
}

private void Audio_PlaybackEnded(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Check if next playlist element exists
    if(Playlist.IndexOf(PlaylistSelectedItem) + 1 < Playlist.Count)
    {
        PlaylistSelectedItem = Playlist[Playlist.IndexOf(PlaylistSelectedItem) + 1];
        if (audio.IsPlaying) audio.Stop();
        audio.Load(GetStreamFromFile(PlaylistSelectedItem.Name + ".wav"));
        audio.Play();
        audio.PlaybackEnded += Audio_PlaybackEnded;
    }else if(audio.IsPlaying) audio.Stop();   
}


private void StopAudio()
{
    if (audio.IsPlaying)
        audio.Stop();
    ChangeButtonMode(3);
}
```

Comment: Do you full source for your example please?
How would you go to next or prevoius track (ListItem)?